# New to programming, variables/array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

```
  function A(a, b) {
     return a[b] * b;
   }
  function B(a) {

     var x = 0;
     for (var i=5; i>0; i--)
     x += A(a, i);

     return x;
  }
      var aValues = [3,5,9,8,7,1];
      var y = B(aValues);
```

Would the answer be:
B(1)
B(3)
B(5)
B(7)
B(8)
B(9)
? 
Im lost be any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What language is that and where does the code come from?

Comment: I'm guessing this is Javascript? And by answer, do you mean the value of `y`? Because if that was the case, y should just be an integer...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E7dXP/ try this in a fiddle :)

Comment: "The answer" is 42. Or what's the question?

Comment: i think it is javascript and i think the answer is 80, I got some help, it should be a=aValues and B is i. So it would work out as 1*5 x=5,  then 4*7 then x=5+28, 3*8 then x=33+24, 2*9 then x=57+18, 1*5 then x=75+5, x=80 so var y=80? Im sorry for the lack of information given.

Comment: "i" will reduce by 1 each time the function is called until all the values are run?

Comment: I apologize I thought i listed the question. Using the following code, what is the value of the variable y at the end of the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the execution y is 80.
The complete array is passed to `B()`. The loop in `B()` iterates over the last 5 elements of `aValues`. Arrays in Javascript start at index 0, so the loop `i=5; i>0; i--` never touches the array element with index 0

Function `a()` then multiplies the current item with the current index and returns the result (which is added to x)

So for every loop index you get:

```
i=5 -> x += 1 * 5
i=4 -> x += 7 * 4
i=3 -> x += 8 * 3
i=2 -> x += 9 * 2
i=1 -> x += 5 * 1
```

So after the loop x contains the value 80 which is returned and assigned to y

Comment: Thank you for the help. That was the explanation I needed.